# Быстрый поиск максимума-минимума

Tags: алгоритм, структуры

Подскажите структуры, которые умеют искать **максимум-минимум** на любом интервале массива (длина до 10000000) за O(1).

Comment: P.S. в метках я ввёл структуры данных, а отобразилось: 
данные  струтуры
Так должно быть (метки разделяются по пробелам)?

Comment: Метка не должна содержать пробелы, иначе слова считаются разными метками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем корректно задан вопрос. Если длина строго ограничена, то формально простой перебор элементов массива на любом интервале будет работать за O(1)
.
Будем считать, что предполагается сложность от числа элементов и информацию об ограничении длины массива мы в оценке сложности не используем. Тогда данная задача состоит из препроцессинга данных и собственно ответов на запросы о минимумах и максимумах. Соответственно, чем больше сложность препроцессинга, тем эффективнее можно давать ответы на запросы, и наоборот. Всё зависит от используемой структуры данных.

Формальный ответ на вопрос звучит так: чтобы сложность ответа на запросы была O(1) - то нужно заранее составить матрицы минимумов и максимумов (строки - начала интервалов, столбцы - концы) и просто по запросу выдавать заранее посчитанный результат из матрицы. 
Но вряд ли это, то что нас реально интересует, потому как сразу упираемся в максимальную сложность препроцессинга, и нерешенную задачу о том, как сделать его эффективно.

Соответственно истину надо искать в золотой середине между сложностью препроцессинга и ответов на запросы. Золотая середина не даст ни по одному из этих пунктов O(1). Основные структуры данных, которые можно посоветовать для эффективного баланса - это дерево отрезков, либо матрица размера NxlogN с вспомогательными результатами. Эти структуры очень хорошо описаны [вот тут](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor), так что не буду заниматься копипастом. Удачного изучения! А вообще ключевое слово: RMQ (Range Minimum Query).

Answer (score 1):

Первое что приходит на ум это обычный массив (или вектор), в котором есть возможность сохранять во внутренние переменные минимум и максимум, а при добавлении просто сравнивать и делать соответсвующие действия. В итоге поиск минимума и максимума будет происходить мгновенно.

Comment: @shurik
а как это организовать, чтобы оптимально использовать память?

Answer (score -1):

Если количество вычислительных ресурсов неограничено, максимум в массиве любого размера ищется за один условный такт.